# When this site graduates, what will happen to user reps and privileges?

Tags: discussion, support

Will the users lose their privileges, as reps required for graduated sites are as much as 4 times higher than that for Beta sites, or  would the users be given some incentives (extra rep), or simply the reps required for privileges will not change?

Comment: Related: [Reputation/Privileges when a beta becomes a fully fledged site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139432/231188)

Comment: This is also useful: [Reputation requirements compared](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/231188)

Comment: What do you mean **if** the site graduates?  :]

Comment: Ah yeah... It must..

Answer (score 4):

When the site finally graduates, you will keep your rep, but the rep requirement for privileges will change.  Take a look at any graduated sites privilege rep requirements and that is what we will have here.  If you no longer have enough rep for something, you *will* lose the privilege until you increase your rep.

Some notable changes are:

- Close votes: 500 -> 3000 rep
- Mod tools: 2000 -> 10000 rep
- Edit without review: 1000 -> 2000 rep
- Create tags: 150 -> 1500 rep

Comment: …for most folks the change they'll notice is mod tools going away (most of the other rep changes aren't as drastic). Of course there may also be a moderator election on graduation so there's that too :)

Answer (score 0):

From everything I've read and heard, you keep the same amount of reputation but how much rep is required for various privileges is changed (goes up).  Thus, you lose any privileges you don't have the rep for in the new system.

As a side note, we aren't really all that close to graduation, so I wouldn't worry about it too much just yet...

Answer (score 0):

reps earned will remain the same.

Requirement for the privileges will increase and people that fail to meet the new requirement will not have the privilege anymore.